# How to optimize this JavaScript/jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of this "animation blocks" in js file and it's very load the page. How can I optimize it? Give me the right direction.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//  second-section animation
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceTop = $("#animate_blocks").offset().top - $(window).height();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#slidebox2").animate({"bottom":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutQuart"});
            else
                $("#slidebox2").stop(true).animate({"bottom": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#slidebox3").animate({"left":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutQuart"});
            else
                $("#slidebox3").stop(true).animate({"left": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#slidebox4").animate({"right":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutQuart"});
            else
                $("#slidebox4").stop(true).animate({"right": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#slidebox6").animate({"right":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 600, easing: "easeOutQuart"});
            else
                $("#slidebox6").stop(true).animate({"right": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#slidebox7").animate({"left":"0px", "opacity": "1", "z-index": "1"},{duration: 600, easing: "easeOutQuart"});
            else
                $("#slidebox7").stop(true).animate({"left": "-300px", "opacity": "0", "z-index": "-1"},200);
        });


    //  advantage-box animation

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceTop = $("#name-list").offset().top - $(window).height();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#advantages-heading").animate({"right":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutBack"});
            else
                $("#advantages-heading").stop(true).animate({"right": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#advantages-text").animate({"left":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutBack"});
            else
                $("#advantages-text").stop(true).animate({"left": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);

        });

    //  mobile-box animation

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceTop = $("#mobile-img").offset().top - $(window).height();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#mobile-heading").animate({"left":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 300, easing: "easeOutBack"});
            else
                $("#mobile-heading").stop(true).animate({"left": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#mobile-text").animate({"right":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 300, easing: "easeOutBack"});
            else
                $("#mobile-text").stop(true).animate({"right": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $("#mobile-img").delay(200).animate({"bottom":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 300, easing: "easeOutBack"});
            else
                $("#mobile-img").stop(true).animate({"bottom": "-150px", "opacity": "0"},200);

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is always the same so you can group them in one if and else, and also use a counter

```
       $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceTop = $("#animate_blocks").offset().top - $(window).height();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
            {
               for ( var counter = 2; counter <= 7; counter++)
               {
                   $("#slidebox"+counter).animate({"bottom":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutQuart"});
               }
            }
            else
               for ( var counter = 2; counter <= 7; counter++)
               {
                   $("#slidebox"+counter).stop(true).animate({"bottom": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Few Optimized code for 2 other condition  check it may be useful.

this for below two conditions

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


    //  advantage-box animation

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceTop = $("#name-list").offset().top - $(window).height();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop){
                $("#advantages-heading").animate({"right":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutBack"});
               $("#advantages-text").animate({"left":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 500, easing: "easeOutBack"});
            }else{
                $("#advantages-heading").stop(true).animate({"right": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
                $("#advantages-text").stop(true).animate({"left": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
            } 

        });

    //  mobile-box animation

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceTop = $("#mobile-img").offset().top - $(window).height();
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop){
                $("#mobile-heading").animate({"left":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 300, easing: "easeOutBack"});
         $("#mobile-text").animate({"right":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 300, easing: "easeOutBack"});
               $("#mobile-img").delay(200).animate({"bottom":"0px", "opacity": "1"},{duration: 300, easing: "easeOutBack"});
          }  else{
                $("#mobile-heading").stop(true).animate({"left": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
                $("#mobile-text").stop(true).animate({"right": "-300px", "opacity": "0"},200);
                $("#mobile-img").stop(true).animate({"bottom": "-150px", "opacity": "0"},200);
         }

        });
});
```